# Copy Contents of 1st page of Word Doc. to Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to copy two specific pieces of information from a word document into an excel sheet.
However, I currently can only copy the entire word doc., which is sometimes too big to copy, and other times it fails on the paste special.

I convert a PDF invoice into word doc. and then I want to copy the State from the "Delivery Address" and the name from "Contact Person"
[image: INVOICE EXAMPLE]

this is what I have so far:

```
Sub My_Attempt_PDFtoDOCXtoEXCEL()
Dim s As String
Dim t As Excel.Range
s = "\\my path\my file.pdf"
Dim wd As New Word.Application
Dim mydoc As Word.Document
Set mydoc = wd.Documents.Open(fileName:=s, Format:="PDF Files", ConfirmConversions:=False)
Dim wr As Word.Range
Set wr = mydoc.Paragraphs(1).Range ' I think this needs changed
wr.WholeStory ' and potentially this too
Set t = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
wr.Copy
t.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
mydoc.Close False
wd.Quit
End Sub
```

can someone please provide some assistance?

Comment: Step through your code and, after the `Set mydoc =..` line has been executed, open the _Locals_ window, and expand the `mydoc` node - expand sub-nodes as necessary until you find some of the invoice text in the `Value` field of a node.

Comment: Your screenshot is of no value to anyone attempting to help as it doesn't show the non-printing characters. You can display these in Word by using the Show/Hide button on the ribbon, or use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+* (Ctrl+Shift+8)

Comment: Thank you all. Spectral, I am struggling to find the necessary text in the nodes. Timothy, thank you and I apologize, i've updated my screenshot.

Comment: It will be something like `myDoc.Paragraphs.Item(1).Range.Text`. The 'browsing' can also be undertaken more efficiently in the Word VBE editor, where you can just query  `ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Item(1).Range.Text`

Comment: If you can be certain that the format of the invoices will always be consistent, now that you can see the end of paragraph marks you can simply count them to find which paragraphs contain the data you need. For example, it looks as though `mydoc.Paragraphs(9).Range` may contain the name and `mydoc.Paragraphs(13).Range` may contain the State.

Comment: Thank you @TimothyRylatt. I noticed there was some inconsistency with which paragraph the data I needed was in. So I resolved this by looping through the first 20 paragraphs. Thanks again!